# how to check if strings in C# contain numbers greater than 9

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to check individual strings of unknown size to see if they contain numbers less than 9 but greater than 1 and there are spaces separating the numbers. For example.

```
  String 1= 1 2 3 
  String 2= 3 4 66 7 4 3
  String 3= 0 9 7 2
```

String 2 and 3 contain numbers which i do not want '66' and '0' respectively.

I am currently using nested if statements but i was thinking there would be a  better way using Regex, however i am new to Regex notation so don't really no much.

Is there a better way?.

To make the question clear, i am trying to find out if a string contains any number greater than 9 or less then 1. Where the string contains spaces between each number.

Comment: What should happen with 66? split it to two sperate numbers?

Comment: I can give you a regex that will match `0` and `66`, but I can't know whether or not it's a better way than what you're already doing without seeing your code.

Comment: The 66 is supposed to be 66

Comment: I think you are looking for a `Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\b[0-9]{2,}\b")`. If a match is found, the string is a "bad" one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `"01"`

Comment: This regex won't consider 10 20...

Comment: @SamIam: There are no values like `01` in the input OP shows. There are other assumptions, too, in that suggestion of mine. The question is very unclear.

Comment: If you just want to validate the string for 1 <= n <= 9, it would be `^(?:\D*(?<!\S)[1-9](?!\S)\D*)+$` If you just want to know if exists numbers outside 1-9 it would be `(?<!\S)(?:0|[1-9]\d+)(?!\S)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution worked thank you

Comment: That solution doesn't work..

Comment: @Wuffle: If my suggestion worked for you, then you should have explained the requirements better. I just made lots of assumptions.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew what other details did you need to know, i thought the question was rather straight forward.

Comment: @Wiffle - If you're a newbie to regex, you cannot see the pitfalls that others can see that result in particular combination of constructs. When it comes to regex, the devil is in the details. I.e. garbage-in = garbage-out.

Comment: @sln  I am very much a newbie to regex, i am sorry if it caused confusion.

Comment: @Wiffle - No, it's not you, you seem pretty new here. Someone will probably come along and post a SO link for you (or you can search yourself) that defines how to ask a question. There is a reason you're sitting on a 4 count close vote right now.

Answer (score 2):

RegEx is the wrong tool.  Try splitting the string on the space and using any method you want to convert the individual elements of the string array to `int`s.  Here I chose LINQ.

This is off the top of my head.. you may need to adjust it to compile.

```
//assuming your strings are in a List<String>
List<string> strings = ...;
List<int> numbers = null;

// assumes you want to work with each set of numbers individually
foreach (string item in strings) {
    numbers = (from n in item.Split(" ") select int.Parse(n)).ToList();
    // TODO: remove numbers out of range, or whatever other processing you want to do.
}
```

Comment: what if the string contains things that are not numbers?

Comment: @SamIam: Then the OP should have mentioned that in their question.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your string to a list of ints and then use linq to find all numbers greater than 9.  TryParse will catch any strings that aren't numbers and set them to -1.

```
int i; 
List<int> intList = stringArray.Split(' ').Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out i) ? i : -1).ToList();
var results = intList.FindAll(x=> x > 9);
```

Answer (score -3):

WiktorStribiżew provided an answer that works for me thank you for your help.

```
Regex.IsMatch(numScreens, @"\b[0-9]{2,}\b")
```

Comment: Like I said, this doesn't work..